# SharePoint SPSite Method dependency issue

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, mysite

I am working on `sharepoint dll` to get the information of the `mysites` say name , user id , picture and for that I am using the sharepoint `SPSite` method but when I run (debug )the code  from the visual studio (not deployed anywhere ) I gets the dependency error saying that..

```
 Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable.
```

By default project target is `Any Cpu` ..

and when i made it to 64 bit i gets the below error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'x' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

means it is giving error for both 32 and 64 bit ..
what could be the reason

Comment: Is SharePoint installed on your development machine?

Comment: @Serv YES its installed..